# Knockout remove rateLimit from observable

Tags: knockout.js

I have an observable which a user can edit. I've added a timeout before the observable should be re-evaluated on changes like this:

```
userInput.extend({ rateLimit: { timeout: 200, method: "notifyWhenChangesStop" }});
```

How can I remove this property from the observable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working. Just needed to write

```
userInput.extend({ rateLimit: false});
```